# multiple consecutive citations in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, citing

I'm creating a presentation using beamer and I want to add citations that will appear as [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKeUv.png)-[3] for example. When I write a paper I use \usepackge{cite} and just do \cite{source1, source2, source3} and it works.
For some reason that doesn't work with beamer, the citation just appears as [1,2,3].
Does anyone know why?
Short example:
Presentation source:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
%
% Choose how your presentation looks.
%
% For more themes, color themes and font themes, see:
% http://deic.uab.es/~iblanes/beamer_gallery/index_by_theme.html
%

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{serif}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}



\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \end{beamercolorbox}%
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
            \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}

\title[]{bla}
\author{3}
\institute{

}

\date{June, 2020}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Outline}
    \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item cite \cite{abc, acv, asd}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{References}
    \bibliography{test_bib}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

test_bib.bib:

```
@inproceedings{abc,
  title={{ad}},
  author={aa},
  booktitle={aa},
  pages={1416--1420},
  year={2003},
  organization={IEEE}
}
@article{acv,
  title={asd},
  author={ff},
  journal={sdf},
  volume={57},
  number={10},
  pages={6633--6649},
  year={2100},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{asd,
  title={deep learning},
  author={dd},
  booktitle={Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
  pages={9436--9446},
  year={2018}
}
```

the result is :

[image: result]

while I want it to be [1]-[3].

Thanks

Comment: In your question you say you use `\usepackage{cite}`, but you have tagged your question with `biblatex` (of `\usepackage{biblatex}`), which is completely incompatible with `cite`. Which one are you using? (The answer will crucially depend on which package you use.) Please show us a short example document that reproduces what you are getting at the moment and shows what bibliography/citation packages and settings you use.

Comment: The question about which style is recommended for computer science presentations is probably largely opinion based (and quite possibly also off-topic, since it is a general question that transcends LaTeX or a particular implementation). Just pick a style you like or look at related works in your field. STEM fields often use some sort of numeric style, which means that pretty much all 'default' styles should be OK.

Comment: added code for example, and yes you are right about biblatex. I do not use it.